# Error with Facebook redirect URL on login/register using passport on a node.js (MEAN stack) application

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, passport.js, mean-stack, passport-facebook

I am implementing the Facebook login and register functions to my application, and can reach facebook for the user to enter their information, but can't make the callback work.  I have input the code below into passport.js (obviously x'ing out our information):

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
clientID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
clientSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
callbackURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/auth/facebook/callback/",
enableProof: false,
profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos']
},
function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
 process.nextTick(function () {

 User.findOne({facebookId: profile.id}, function (err, user) {

  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }

  if (user) {

    return done(null, user);

  } else {

    var data = {
      facebookId: profile.id,
      f_name: profile.first_name,
      l_name: profile.last_name,
      username: profile.email
    };

    if (profile.emails && profile.emails[0] && profile.emails[0].value)            {
      data.username = profile.emails[0].value;
    }

    User.create(data, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
});
});
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, callback) {
  callback(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
 User.findById({
 _id: id
 }, function(err, user) {
  callback(err, user);
 });
});  

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
 function (username, password, done) {
   console.log(username);
   console.log(password);
User.findOne({ 'username': username }, function (err, user) {
  // if (err) { return done(err); }
  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email.' });
  }
  if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
  }
  return done(null, user);
});
 }
));
```

The following callback URL has been included in index.js:

```
   router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { 
   scope: 'email' }));

 router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/user/#/home',
        failureRedirect : '/'
    }));
```

I am able to make the application direct to the Facebook login page onClick, but once the user enters their email and password into facebook, the application is unable to reload on redirect and get the person to our homepage.  The redirect begins to happen, but hits an error once it tries to load our application. Could we be utilizing one of the redirect fields incorrectly?  As a side note, what should we set as a valid OAuth Redirect URI on the facebook developer application page?

Comment: Read it twice and don't know what the error is other than "unable to reload on redirect and get the person to our homepage" 

The beauty of Facebook API is that if you hit the API or dialog OAUTH you will always get a response or error.

So please look in your error log or make a simplified version of your passport.js app to determine where the cause will be.

A shot in the dark which seems to be a problem for a lot of people is the trailing devs forget to place in the callback URL either in the app settings or the passport.js configuration.

Comment: this is the exact error we get: Failed to load resource: https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQAZmnNT67_ICFr…thuPYt4xAKoDUZY&state=d9d0131c606477230ca10c658f792190adfa5f118593bd9d#_=_  the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).  We have placed https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/auth/facebook/callback/" as the callback URL

Comment: Check server logs in terminal when you run the request, post error here.

Comment: the error posted above is the console response error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error): https://xxxxxxxxx.com/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQBEHye-GLiWJ7_…ZYTQNkeOSiXXWSE&state=73ac8eb8c4c4ab6cc83c730906f41b8f991e0b02be682ec8#_=_

Comment: When I preserve the logs the GET request also throws a 500 for: /users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQAqlZehRUtr_Tos6sEtNGY0HXaq_jfi20VtoJEL…0d6xm_eeoadto&state=73ac8eb8c4c4ab6cc83c730906f41b8f991e0b02be682ec8#_=_:1